# `helm-find-files` with other window as default action

Tags: helm

I would like a helm replacement for `find-file-other-window`—one that acts like `helm-find-files` but has `helm-find-files-other-window` as the default action.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm not perfectly clear what you're looking for. In my setup, `C-x C-f` does `helm-find-files`, and `C-x 4 C-f` does `find-file-other-window` wrapped with a Helm interface. Does that sound like what you want?

Comment: I have that too but it doesn't work quite the same way that `helm-find-files` does. For example, it doesn't seem to have the same behavior for finding files as point. `C-h m` suggests using the fully featured `helm-find-files` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The first action is the default action, so you can change the first element of `helm-find-files-actions` to `helm-find-files-other-window`, use e.g.:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'helm-files
  (push '("Find file other window `C-c o'" . helm-find-files-other-window)
        helm-find-files-actions)
  (delete-dups helm-find-files-actions))
```

If you use Emacs's custom system, you can also use `M-x customise-variable helm-find-files-actions`, this way should require less emacs lisp knowledge.

---

Personally, I use `helm-find-files-other-window` a lot as well. However, instead of making it as the default action, I just bind a shorter key (`M-o`) to it.

```
(define-key helm-find-files-map [?\M-o] #'helm-ff-run-switch-other-window)
```

Comment: Very useful! Is there a way to have a new command with this default and still retain the original behavior for `helm-find-files`?

Comment: Yes, just change the value of `helm-find-files-actions` locally and call `helm-find-files` in the new command, for example, `(let ((helm-find-files-actions  ...)) (helm-find-files))`.